# Deciphering a specific response from a Broadcom mobile GPS module

Tags: gps, linux-device-driver, reverse-engineering, spi, broadcom

So far I have managed to work with the GPS module "Broadcom 4775x CSP Hub Lib ver 408635". However, the responses from the module are not standardized and it was impossible for me to decipher the responses. Perhaps I don't know much about decrypting the responses and how GPS modules work. The drivers for the module were found in the kernel kernel of the Google Pixel 6 smartphone.
The module chip sends this response:

```hexdump
00000e40: ec 89 eb 93 cb 99 29 00 c0 c4 ff b0 01 b0 00 a5  ......).........
00000e50: 6b 00 1f 80 68 66 00 c0 c1 02 80 60 00 47 31 58  k...hf.....`.G1X
00000e60: 00 6b 91 ab 84 0b 82 4b ff 0c f7 ec 86 0b 86 6b  .k.....K.......k
00000e70: 89 ab 84 cb 05 02 19 29 9b cd 99 0e ae ae cd 2e  .......)........
00000e80: 99 8e ed 6e aa 0e df 4f b2 ce 87 cd 99 2d 81 8d  ...n...O.....-..
00000e90: 81 ed ba 0e ee 2f ba 4f 93 6d 81 8d f2 ae d3 0e  ...../.O.m......
00000ea0: 8d ce bb 6e aa 8d 91 ad b3 ce d5 2f cc 4e 8b 6d  ...n......./.N.m
00000eb0: 8e ce c5 af 9b 2e a0 ae f6 2b 00 c0 c4 37 b0 01  .........+...7..
00000ec0: b0 00 a6 b9 00 1f 80 b6 b4 00 c0 c1 02 80 ae 00  ................
00000ed0: 66 3b a5 00 cf 97 2e c8 2e e0 02 ee c1 ee ae 4e  f;.............N
00000ee0: 87 4d 9a 8d 31 32 c1 00 1f 41 4b 6d ac f0 8d 9a  .M..12...AKm....
00000ef0: cc 00 20 04 00 02 b9 26 00 01 b5 31 00 05 c5 03  .. ....&...1....
00000f00: 00 00 91 ba 00 09 2b 77 00 01 07 e3 00 10 3f 48  ......+w......?H
```

You can get this response from the module. The response depends on the output method.

```hexdump
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
```

I noticed that every module response starts with "b0 00". And often end up "b0 XX". XX are different characters, e.g. 01, 03.:

```hexdump
b0 00 3a 4b 00 1f 80 48 46 00 c0 c1 02 80 40 00  ..:K...HF.....@.
2f 1a 38 00 03 ad a1 93 ff e6 f3 c1 03 47 68 b7  /.8..........Gh.
00 4a a6 a9 03 c8 72 c5 00 00 00 00 03 5e bf c1  .J....r......^..
ff b8 06 a8 02 55 84 25 ff 93 19 ba 02 37 77 d4  .....U.%.....7w.
00 62 a3 22 00 0a e0 02 aa ff fd cc eb 00 c0 c4  .b."............
06 b0 01 b0 00 3b 34 00 1f 80 31 2f 00 c0 c1 02  .....;4...1/....
80 28 00 b7 06 20 00 c0 c0 41 e0 03 05 06 0a 43  .(... ...A.....C
01 07 07 07 07 07 5a 39 03 8f 56 51 01 0f 00 00  ......Z9..VQ....
00 2a ae b5 1c 00 00 08 ed 00 c0 c4 eb b0 01     .*.............
```

```hexdump
b0 00 3a 4b 00 1f 80 48 46 00 c0 c1 02 80 40 00  ..:K...HF.....@.
2f 1a 38 00 03 ad a1 93 ff e6 f3 c1 03 47 68 b7  /.8..........Gh.
00 4a a6 a9 03 c8 72 c5 00 00 00 00 03 5e bf c1  .J....r......^..
ff b8 06 a8
```

```hexdump
b0 00 3c f3 00 1f 80 f0 ee 00 c0 c1 02 80 e8 00
97 6f e0 00 20 00 00 00 28 1e d0 f3 00 7f d5 00
b9 f2 e8 03 0d e9 03 0e e0 04 03 0e 53 03 0e 6f
03 0e 7c 00 00 04 e0 03 00 00 51 67 5b e0 01 e0
00 e5 00 db e0 03 02 06 60 02 8a a8 5d 2f cc 53
00 fa fe ad c9 2e 8b 08 fc 93 d0 cd 00 10 99 8b
bd ea c3 69 8a c8 d7 29 b1 6a 87 cb c6 ec 92 6b
bc cb 86 aa ad 2a 95 8a bf ab 81 8b 80 6b 05 02
19 29 de 2e d4 4d d7 8d c7 ac 8a aa a4 6b 82 0d
e0 02 6d a2 6d a2 8d da 0e ba ac a9 cb bc 4c cb
4e fd 4e 92 8d bf cd 81 0d 8f 6b 99 aa 8c 4b 85
2e df ed b5 0e af 6d d7 ad 9f ec f4 ec 9a 8c 85
6e e2 ee be ee cb 0d bb 2e c8 cc e3 6b da ec ad
8e 80 6d 0b 08 b9 f2 69 75 a8 47 49 fb 09 d7 ec
00 00 00 00 0f 43 34 ff fc 8d b8 00 21 9e 18 ff
fd
```

Please help me decipher the answers. What algorithm should I use to decode the answers to get human-readable answers?

I've tried different ways of outputting the answers, but always get a coded result.

```c
static ssize_t bcm_spi_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct bcm_spi_priv *priv = filp->private_data;
    struct circ_buf *circ = &priv->read_buf;
    size_t rd_size = 0;

    mutex_lock(&priv->rlock);

    print_hex_dump(KERN_ERR, "bcm_gps_spi.c Circ Buffer: ", DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, 32, 1, circ->buf, BCM_SPI_READ_BUF_SIZE, true);

    /*
     * Copy from circ buffer to user
     * We may require 2 copies from [tail..end] and [end..head]
     */
    do {
        size_t cnt_to_end = CIRC_CNT_TO_END(
                circ->head, circ->tail, BCM_SPI_READ_BUF_SIZE);
        size_t copied = min(cnt_to_end, size);

        //pr_err("bcm_gps_spi.c GPSCHK copied = %zu\n", copied);

        if (copy_to_user(buf + rd_size,
                circ->buf + circ->tail, copied)){
            dev_err(&priv->spi->dev, "failed to copy to user.\n");
            mutex_unlock(&priv->rlock);
            return -EFAULT;
        }
        
print_hex_dump(KERN_ERR, "bcm_gps_spi.c Data: ", DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, 32, 1, circ->buf + circ->tail, copied, true);

        size -= copied;
        rd_size += copied;
        circ->tail = (circ->tail + copied) & (BCM_SPI_READ_BUF_SIZE-1);

    } while (size > 0 && CIRC_CNT(circ->head,
                circ->tail, BCM_SPI_READ_BUF_SIZE));
    mutex_unlock(&priv->rlock);

#ifdef DEBUG_1HZ_STAT
    bbd_update_stat(priv->bbd, STAT_RX_LHD, rd_size);
#endif

    return rd_size;
}
```

```c
static ssize_t bbd_common_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t size, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct bbd_device *bbd = filp->private_data;
    unsigned int minor = iminor(filp->f_path.dentry->d_inode);
    struct circ_buf *circ = &bbd->priv[minor].read_buf;
    size_t rd_size = 0;
    char temp_buf[512];
    char temp_buf2[512];
    unsigned char *data_ptr;
    size_t i; size_t log_size; char c;

    if (minor >= BBD_DEVICE_INDEX) {
        WARN_ON(minor >= BBD_DEVICE_INDEX);
        goto out;
    }

    mutex_lock(&bbd->priv[minor].lock);

    /*
     * Copy from circ buffer to lhd
     * Because lhd's buffer is linear,
     * we may require 2 copies from [tail..end] and [end..head]
     */
    do {
        size_t cnt_to_end = CIRC_CNT_TO_END(circ->head,
                circ->tail, BBD_BUFF_SIZE);
        size_t copied = min(cnt_to_end, size);
        //pr_info("bbd.c: bbd_common_read check buf: %02x \n", buf + rd_size);
        if (copy_to_user(buf + rd_size,
                (void *) circ->buf + circ->tail, copied)) {
            mutex_unlock(&bbd->priv[minor].lock);
            rd_size = -EFAULT;
            goto out;
        }

        // Logging the data in hex format
        print_hex_dump(KERN_ERR, "bbd.c GPS Data Hex: ", DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, 16, 1, circ->buf + circ->tail, copied, false);
        
        // Copy data to temp_buf for ASCII logging
        log_size = min(copied, sizeof(temp_buf) - 1);
        memcpy(temp_buf, circ->buf + circ->tail, log_size);
        temp_buf[log_size] = '\0'; // Ensure null-termination

        // Logging as ASCII - this may not be meaningful if data is in a binary format
        pr_err("bbd.c bbd_common_read GPS Data ASCII: %s\n", temp_buf);

    // Attempt to interpret the data as ASCII (for NMEA-like formats)
    for (i = 0; i < copied && i < sizeof(temp_buf) - 1; ++i) {
         c = circ->buf[circ->tail + i];
        temp_buf2[i] = (c >= 32 && c <= 126) ? c : '.'; // Replace non-printable characters with '.'
    }
    temp_buf2[i] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the string
    pr_err("bbd.c GPSCHK bbd_common_read Interpreted Data: %s\n", temp_buf2);

    data_ptr = circ->buf + circ->tail;

        size -= copied;
        rd_size += copied;
        circ->tail = (circ->tail + copied) & (BBD_BUFF_SIZE - 1);

    } while (size > 0 && CIRC_CNT(circ->head, circ->tail, BBD_BUFF_SIZE));

    mutex_unlock(&bbd->priv[minor].lock);

    bbd_log_hex(bbd->db, bbd_dev_name[minor], buf, rd_size);

#ifdef DEBUG_1HZ_STAT
    bbd_update_stat(bbd, STAT_RX_LHD, rd_size);
#endif
out:
    return rd_size;
}
```

There is a logging function within the drivers. But this function again does not help to decrypt the responses. It outputs the answers in the same form that I got.

```c
static void pk_log(struct bcm_spi_priv *priv, char *dir,
        unsigned char *data, int len)
{
    const char ic = 'D';

    if (likely(!priv->bbd->ssi_dbg))
        return;

    /*
     * TODO: There is print issue. Printing 7 digits instead of 6
     * when clock is over 1000000. "% 1000000" added
     * E.g.
     * #999829D w 0x68,  1: A2
     * #999829D r 0x68, 34: 8D 00 01 52 5F B0 01 B0 00 8E 00 01 53 8B
     * B0 01 B0 00 8F 00 01 54 61 B0 01 B0 00 90 00 01 55 B5
     *          r B0 01
     * #1000001D w 0x68, 1: A1
     * #1000001D r 0x68, 1: 00
     */
    dev_info(&priv->spi->dev, "#%06ld%c %2s,\t  %5d: ",
            bcm_clock_get_ms() % 1000000, ic, dir, len);

    print_hex_dump(KERN_INFO, dir[0] == 'r' ? "r " : "w ",
            DUMP_PREFIX_NONE, 32, 1, data, len, false);
}
```

I thought the module was supposed to send responses in NMEA video, but most likely the module is sending responses in its own binary format.

Comment: BCM uses proprietary protocol that is handled by a user space driver (kernel driver is a "proxy" in that sense, see how nVidia does their driver, for example). You need to reverse-engineer that protocol.

Comment: Btw, have you seen https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gpsd-dev/2013-08/msg00001.html, https://iam.tj/projects/meif_protocol/ and this https://redmine.replicant.us/projects/replicant/wiki/BCM4751?

Comment: When the chip starts up, it writes something that looks like a dictionary. But it doesn't do anything for me.
`b0 00 31 00 05 2f 2e 9f b0 01 ..1../....
...
b0 00 41 00 05 3f 3e c8 b0 01 ..A..?>...
...
b0 00 7a 00 05 78 77 8d b0 01 ..z..xw...`
The only option I've seen is to make my own dictionary of bit-to-symbol transcription by the search and match method.